# Pre-filling Field tag in redux-form with text

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I'm trying to prefill a Field tag with data being passed as props.

Here is how the Field tag looks like now:

```
    <Field
      name="name"
      type="text"
      label="Role name"
      placeholder="Role"
      value={role.name}
      component={BSFieldInput}
   />
```

I added this attribute `value={role.name}`, but it seems it's not setting the value. Can anyone point me to the right direction.

Comment: in the **placeholder**, I try to replace the **Role** with **{role.name}**, and it worked but I'm still wondering why it doesn't work for **value**

Answer (score 0):

Redux Form passed a function called `initialize` as prop to your component which is connected to redux form.

So, you can read initialize your form when your component mounts.

```
componentDidMount(){
  const { initialize} = this.props
  const obj = {
   'name' : '//value'   //the key is same as your field name
  }
  initialize(obj)
}
```

You can read [redux-form-docs](http://redux-form.com/6.1.1/examples/initializeFromState/) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Harkirat, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue I posted earlier.

Instead of adding a **value** attribute to the **Field tag**, you need to set initialValues in the mapStateToProps. Here is how:

```
const mapStateToprops = (state, ownProps) => {
   return {
     initialValues: ownProps.role
   }
}
```

For further understanding, you can checkout: http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/examples/initializeFromState/

Thanks for contributing.